# printf() in C: How do I keep my floats/double from rounding?

Tags: c, printf

Been trying to get the outputs to give me the number without rounding, not sure what I'm missing

```
float NumberOfTrees1;

for (NumberOfTrees1 = 1000.0; NumberOfTrees1 >= 50; NumberOfYears++)
{
    NumberOfTrees1 = NumberOfTrees1 - (NumberOfTrees1 * 0.13);
    printf("Number of Remaining Trees: %0.1f\n",NumberOfTrees1);
}
```

My Output:

```
Number of Remaining Trees: 61.7
Number of Remaining Trees: 53.7
Number of Remaining Trees: 46.7
```

Required Output:

```
Number of Remaining Trees: 61
Number of Remaining Trees: 53
Number of Remaining Trees: 46
```

I understand that the `%0.1f` is what gives me the `.7` but when I use `%0.0f` it rounds **up** my numbers which I don't want. Been switching things around from using `int`, `double`, `long float` etc to no avail.

Any help would be great and thank you in advance!!!

Comment: By subtracting n*0.13 you're likely to have decimals. What don't you want: 46.7 rounded up to 47 or down to 46, or both?

Comment: You may be interested in the `floor()` function.

Comment: Read the http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Printf rounds to nearest, not round up

Comment: `double` (and `float`) itself is rounded naturally (`0.1 + 0.2` results in a rounded `0.3`)... but just use `"%a"` to print all the bits (in hexadecimal): `printf("0.3 rounded is %a\n", 0.1 + 0.2);`

Comment: Try `printf("Number of Remaining Trees: %.0f\n", floorf(NumberOfTrees1));`

Answer (score 1):

[Antonin GAVRELs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3161139/antonin-gavrel) answer should print the desired output, but if you don't want to cast the floating point numbers into integers, you could use the `double floor (double x)` function from `<math.h>`.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    double x =  53.7;
    double floored = floor(x);
    printf("⌊%0.1lf⌋ = %0.1lf\n", x, floored);

    return 0;
}
```

The program can be compiled with `-lm` and prints the following when executed:

```
⌊53.7⌋ = 53.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast into `int` in order to truncate your number:

```c
int main(void) {
    double d =  53.7;
    float f = 46.7f;

    int a = (int)d;
    int b = (int)f;

    printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
}
```

output:

```
53 46
```

Or, as suggested by @user3386109, you may use floor(), but you will need to also include <math.h> header and compile with `-lm`

Comment: Is there any other way other than casting it into "int"? I'm taking a class and we haven't covered that as well as using floor(). Thank you though

Comment: you can use floor function from libc which truncates the number

Comment: Why do you use the suffix `f` on the float? It's only needed on the double.

Comment: its only needed on the float actually, but thank you for pointing out

Comment: Casting to int won't work if the float value is outside int's range. The only safe way is floor

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL Oh, then I guess I've done it wrong the whole time lol.

Comment: @BuddhaPowers :  It the required solution has constraints, you must include them in your question rather than comment on individual solutions.  Your constraints any restrictions on libraries or syntax imposed by your course material.  You don't actually need the _explicit_ cast - simply assigning the float to the int will implicitly cast it.

Comment: @AndySukowski-Bang: In context the cast is entirely safe because in the question the range is clear:  `NumberOfTrees1` <= 1000.0.  The example code in this answer is however generalised (stripped of context) - and in that case you have a point.

Comment: UPVOTE for an answer!!!!! Quick and dirty way of doing this, my only suggestion is, put the NOTE: If you know that your value is larger than MAX_INT cast it to `long` or `long long` instead. What if you do not have math library?